# Make an object appear above VR hand in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm a 3D modeler but have never tried actually programming or making a game before. I've created a scene in Unity and made a camera offset and VR hands using XR components. From here, I'd like to make a map show up above the left hand when a button on the controller is pressed. I can't find any sort of guide on how to do this. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the hand as parent of the map and transform it's position on top of the left hand so that the map will attached to left hand. If the user moves their hands then the map will follow.

For doing that when the controller is pressed then access the components in the script and make map child of left hand.

I am not use which controller is you are using. If you are using samsung gear vr then download the ovr package and use that.